# How to I delete from all Sub Directories apart from a select few

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delete-file

I would like to create 1 batch file that deletes a type of file (i.e. ".bak") with different date ranges situated in different sub folders that are in the same patent folder, but I can list the minority of folders.

I have managed to create a FOR loop to look in certain directories (which the directories are set in a variable), deleting any '*.bak' file over a certain age with the below script:

```
SET "WeeklyBAKLocation=Folder20 Folder21 Folder25 Folder28"
SET WeeklyBAK=7
SET DailyBAK=3

FOR %%x IN (%WeeklyBAKLocation%) DO forfiles /p "%%x" /s /m *.bak /d -%WeeklyBAK% /c "cmd /c DEL @path /q"

<SECOND FOR LOOP below HERE>
```

The above works deleting .bak files older than 7 days in those folders, my question is how can I reverse that and delete '.bak' files in every other directory that's older than 3 days, without deleting the ones kept from the first query?

I tried nesting FOR and FORFILES, using findstr /v to ignore them as below (but it would ignore each directory for that 1 loop, and then delete it for the next loop wouldn't it, so eventually it would not have worked and is massively inefficient?)

```
SET "WeeklyBAKLocation=Folder20 Folder21 Folder25 Folder28"
SET WeeklyBAK=7
SET DailyBAK=3

<First FOR LOOP above HERE>

FOR %%x IN (%WeeklyBAKLocation%) DO FOR /F "delims=*" %%G IN ('dir /b /s "%~dp0" ^| findstr /v "\%%x"') DO forfiles /p "%%G" /s /m *.bak /d -%DailyBAK% /c "cmd /c ECHO @path /q"
```

Essentially can I ignore SOME directories at once when walking through them to find .bak files to delete only ones that are 3 days old.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%G IN (
 'dir /b /s /AD "%~dp0" ^| findstr /v "\%%x"') DO (
 set "zapme=Y"
 FOR %%x IN (%WeeklyBAKLocation%) DO if /i "%%x"=="%%G" set "zapme="
 if defined zapme forfiles /p "%%G" /s /m *.bak /d -%DailyBAK% /c "cmd /c ECHO @path /q"
)
```

read the directory list in basic form (note `/ad`) and for each directory, set `zapme` to *something* then check whether the directory is *not to be processed* and set `zapme` to *nothing* if it's one of those directories. The `zapme` flag can then be tested for being set or not set. If it's set, go ahead and process the directory.

---

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%G IN (
 'dir /b /AD "%sourcedir%"') DO (
  set "zapme=Y"
  FOR %%x IN (%WeeklyBAKLocation%) DO if /i "%%x"=="%%G" set "zapme="
  if defined zapme ECHO forfiles /p "%sourcedir%\%%G" /s /m *.bak /d -%DailyBAK% /c "cmd /c ECHO @path /q"
)
```

...happens every time I don't actually test it...

Comment: Unfortunately this still finds the older .bak files in all directories and doesn't exclude any defined in the %WeeklyBAKLocation% variable